# Repeat an element n number of times in an array

Tags: bash

Basically, I am trying to repeat each element in the following array `[1 2 3]` 4 times such that I will get something like this:
`[1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3]`

I tried a very stupid line of code i.e. `abc=('1%.0s' {1..4})`. But it failed miserably.

I am looking for an efficient one line solution to this problem and preferably, without using loops. If it is not possible to achieve this with just one line, then use loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're trying to avoid loops you can do:

```
arr=(1 2 3)
for i in ${arr[@]}; do for ((n=1; n<=4; n++)) do echo -n "$i ";done; done; echo
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

To store the results in an array:

```
aarr=($(for i in ${arr[@]}; do for ((n=1; n<=4; n++)) do echo -n "$i ";done; done;))
declare -p aarr
declare -a aarr='([0]="1" [1]="1" [2]="1" [3]="1" [4]="2" [5]="2" [6]="2" [7]="2" [8]="3" [9]="3" [10]="3" [11]="3")'
```

Comment: What exactly does declare mean ? I tried `man declare` , but nothing returns in my terminal. In addition , what is the difference between `-p` and `-a` ?

Comment: `-p` will **display the attributes and value of each NAME**, I have used it to print the array. Use `help declare`

Answer (score 1):

This does what you need and stores it in an array:

`declare -a res=($(for v in 1 2 3; do for i in {1..4}; do echo $v; done; done))`

Answer (score 1):

Taking your idea to the next step:

```
$ a=(1 2 3)
$ b=($(for x in "${a[@]}"; do printf "$x%.0s " {1..4}; done))
$ echo ${b[@]}
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Alternatively, using sed:

```
$ echo ${a[*]} | sed -r 's/[[:alnum:]]+/& & & &/g'
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Or, using awk:

```
$ echo ${a[*]} | awk -v RS='[ \n]' '{for (i=1;i<=4;i++)printf "%s ", $0;} END{print""}'
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple one liner:

```
for x in 1 2 3 ; do array+="$(printf "%1.0s$x" {1..4})" ;done
```

Similar to what you wanted.